# micro arduino and w5100

Tags: arduino-uno, ethernet, arduino-micro

I would like to ask if it is possible and how to connect the following module
http://www.ebay.com/itm/TOP-Mini-W5100-LAN-Ethernet-Shield-Network-Module-board-for-Arduino-Best-NEW-/251981053942?pt=LH_DefaultDomain_0&hash=item3aab3dbff6

to the arduino micro

I found some pin layouts but only for Leonardo or Ethernet shield, Uno etc.

Also I've choosen this model because it can be programmed directly in arduino using Sockets API

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While it would have been nice to see your research rather then having to spend some time finding this information myself, I did find this http://www.instructables.com/id/Add-Ethernet-to-any-Arduino-project-for-less-than-/ from what I can see this should be compatible to any arduino as long as it has 3 volt pin and 4 i/o pins. While the arduino micro doesn't have a 3v3 pin, as far as I know, that shouldn't be an issue as long as you can drop the voltage from the 5 volt pin, this module should work for you.

Comment: actually I though the same but wanted to be sure and ask.
Maybe someone knew more!